# Restrict users from changing the account name on the Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, permissions, security, opportunity-lineitem, permission-sets

What is the best way to restrict users from changing the account name on the Opportunities?

Tried making the 'Account' field a read-only field but unfortunately if the Sales Person creates an Opportunity from scratch (not converted with leads or from an existing account) they are stuck as they can't add a company name in!

Ideally the option above is the simplest to do but can you use permission sets or validation rules that allow exceptions (i.e. make it a read-only field only when created?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using validation rule.

```
NOT(ISNEW()) && ISCHANGED(AccountId)
```

And throw error,

> You can't change Account.